# Does Laravel Mix.extract still useful without any frontend framework?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Laravel `Mix.extract()` generate three files

```
manifest.js
vendor.js
[name].js
```

I am currently not using any front end framework which means I have to include `manifest and vendor in every single page/blade`.
Does that mean that all of the vendor libraries must be re-downloaded and cached if a user goes to another page?

Comment: Even if you're not using a front-end framework, chances are you're using some libraries somewhere or other.  When you split them out into a vendor bundle, they won't have to be re-downloaded every time you change some of your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember extract is only used to compile external libraries into separate file so you won't force browser to reload whole code with all the libraries on every small code change. So if you are no using any libraries you don't need to use it.